# Oracle numeric type which start with 0

Tags: sql, oracle

Which I have to use numeric data type(if numeric) in Oracle database, if i will store in that column the values which start with 0. For example 000, 0001, 02.

Comment: You want prefixed numbers... Plan A: you could use a `varchar` type and store the values with their prefix. The real question is, why would you want these prefixes to be stored in the database - wouldn't it be easier to just format them that way when you print them?

Comment: good idea, i'll save it without prefixes

Comment: When selecting data, you can pad them out with zeroes however far you want using `LPAD()`, e.g. `LPAD(my_number_column, 10, '0')`.

Comment: Or use `to_char()` to format your number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That isn't numeric though. In numeric speak 00001 = 0001 = 001 = 01 = 1. They are all the same. If you are looking for something that distinguishes between those you will need a char/varchar column.

Answer (score -3):

You can declare NUMBER (N) where N is your max numbers of digits

to show the leading "0" simple add them in SELECT query
http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/lpad.php

Comment: Of course that's not how you pad with leading zeroes in Oracle.